# parse server - how to extract longitude+latitude from ParseGeoPoint in cloud code

Tags: parse-platform, parse-javascript-sdk, parse-cloud-code

In cloud code, I want to get the longitude and latitude from a geopoint that was stored in the DB.

This is some of what I see in the logs - for afterSave function

```
2019-03-24T13:41:01.130Z - afterSave triggered for abc for user XYZ:
_ Input: {“geo”:{"__type":“GeoPoint”,“latitude”:32.7843083,“longitude”:34.6441017},“image”:_
```

In an afterSave cloud function - I’m reading the geoPint itself by calling:

```js
const geo = request.object.get(“geo”);
```

But how do I get the longitude & latitude from the geo constant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `afterSave` function add the following const for your geoPoint:

```js
const geo = request.object.get("geo");
```

and then, simply refer to:

```
geo.latitude
```

and

```
geo.longitude
```

The same works in any environment running the Parse JavaScript SDK (but your variable declaration would be different).

Answer (score 1):

You can add in your cloud code environment the `afterSave` below:

```
Parse.Cloud.afterSave("Your_class_name", (request) => {

    const geopoint = request.object.get("geo");

    console.log("latitude: " + geopoint.latitude + "\nlongitude: " + geopoint.longitude);
});
```